# mysql pivotar tabla resultado de campos json

Tags: mysql, json

estoy buscando informacion para pivotar una tabla en mysql. La bbdd que tengo es un poco rara, porque los datos los tengo que sacar de un json de uno de los campos. 
Despues de buscar, he conseguido ejecutar la siguiente sentencia:

```
    select
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.assembled')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.assembled'),NULL)) as assembled,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows'),NULL)) as windows,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.osMac')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osMac'),NULL)) as mac,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux'),NULL)) as linux,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard'),NULL)) as sdcard,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.usb')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.usb'),NULL)) as usb,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet'),NULL)) as ethernet,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.wifi')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.wifi'),NULL)) as wifi,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth'),NULL)) as bluetooth,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay'),NULL)) as integratedDisplay,
            count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay'),NULL)) as touchableDisplay, 
from bigdata_filtered
```

Y he obtenido el siguiente resultado:

```
+-----------+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+----------+------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+
| assembled | windows | mac | linux | sdcard | usb | ethernet | wifi | bluetooth | integratedDisplay | touchableDisplay |
+-----------+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+----------+------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+
|         2 |       0 |   0 |     0 |      0 |   0 |       14 |   13 |         0 |                 0 |                0 |
+-----------+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+----------+------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+
```

ahora necesito conseguir algo como:

```
property         count
assembled           0
windows             0
mac                 0
linux               0
sdcard              0
usb                 0
ethernet           14
wifi               13
bluetooth           0
integratedDisplay   0
touchableDisplay    0
```

he visto tutoriales sobre como hacer un pivot con mysql, pero todos los ejemplos son para conseguir lo contrario (Desde lo que quiero hacer, muestran como obtener lo que yo ya tengo)

Alguien se le ocurre como puedo hacerlo? o conoce algun tutorial que explique este caso concreto?

Answer (score 0):

Viendo lo que comentas se me ocurre que, aprovechando que son valores finitos, hagas una consulta por cada tipo que devuelve dos valores, una constante (que será el nombre) y el valor para ese nombre y luego juntar todas con un union (te lo pinto al vuelo que seguro que está mal pero para que cojas mi idea a ver si te sirve):

```
select 
    'assembled' as property,
    count(json_extract(filters, '$.assembled')) as records
            from bigdata_filtered
where json_extract(filters, '$.assembled')= true

union all

select 
    'osWindows' as property,
    count(json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows')) as records
            from bigdata_filtered
where json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows')= true

union all

...
...
...
```

Creo que no es del todo correcto pero creo que se capta la idea.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: genial!!! aunque la he ajustado a lo que me interesaba, ya que luego calculo un % de los valores

Answer (score 0):

Basado en el comentario de Fernando, al final he dejado la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
  select concat("assembled") as field, count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.assembled')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.assembled'),NULL)) / count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered 
union 
  select concat("windows") as field, count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered
union
  select concat("mac") as field,  count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.osMac')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osMac'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered
union
  select concat("linux") as field,  count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered
union
  select concat("sdCard") as field,  count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered
union
  select concat("usb") as field,  count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.usb')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.usb'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered
union
  select concat("ethernet") as field,  count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered
union
  select concat("wifi") as field,  count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.wifi')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.wifi'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered
union
  select concat("bluetooth") as field,  count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered
union
  select concat("integratedDisplay") as field,  count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered
union
  select concat("touchableDisplay") as field,  count(if( json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay'),NULL))/ count(id) * 100 as count
  from bigdata_filtered;
```

Lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve de solucion.

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Angel, si te ha resultado útil mi respuesta marcala. Gracias.