# mysql: campos y count(*) de union

Tags: mysql, sql

A raiz de la consulta que hice hace unos dias ([mysql pivotar tabla resultado de campos json](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37576/mysql-pivotar-tabla-resultado-de-campos-json)) me he encontrado con otro problema. Resulta que tengo que obtener unos campos de varias union y dividirlo por el total de elementos que tiene el union.

actualmente tengo:

```
select
    concat("assembled") as field, concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.assembled')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.assembled'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("windows") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("linux") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("mac") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.osMac')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osMac'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("sdcard") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("usb") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.usb')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.usb'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("ethernet") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("wifi") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.wifi')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.wifi'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("bluetooth") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("Display") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay'),NULL))as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("touchable") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("Camera") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.integratedCamera')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedCamera'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("Scanner") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.builtinScanner')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.builtinScanner'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("mobileApp") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.mobileApp')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.mobileApp'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("Computer") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.integratedComputer')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedComputer'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("closedFrame") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.closedFrame')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.closedFrame'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("securityLock") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.securityLock')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.securityLock'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("emergencyStop") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.emergencyStop')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.emergencyStop'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("innerLight") as field,concat("1") as veces,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.innerLight')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.innerLight'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
```

Esto me genera una tabla con los siguientes datos:

```
+---------------+-------+--------+
| field         | veces | cuenta |
+---------------+-------+--------+
| assembled     | 1     |      1 |
| assembled     | 1     |      9 |
| assembled     | 1     |      0 |
| assembled     | 1     |      8 |
| assembled     | 1     |      4 |
| assembled     | 1     |      6 |
| assembled     | 1     |      5 |
| assembled     | 1     |      7 |
| assembled     | 1     |     17 |
| assembled     | 1     |     11 |
| assembled     | 1     |      3 |
| assembled     | 1     |     14 |
| assembled     | 1     |     13 |
| assembled     | 1     |     15 |
| assembled     | 1     |      2 |
| windows       | 1     |      0 |
| windows       | 1     |      9 |
| windows       | 1     |     25 |
| windows       | 1     |      2 |
| windows       | 1     |      6 |
| windows       | 1     |      5 |
| windows       | 1     |     11 |
| windows       | 1     |      1 |
| windows       | 1     |      8 |
| windows       | 1     |      4 |
| linux         | 1     |      0 |
| linux         | 1     |      4 |
| linux         | 1     |     11 |
| linux         | 1     |      1 |
| linux         | 1     |      9 |
| linux         | 1     |      8 |
| mac           | 1     |      0 |
| mac           | 1     |      9 |
| mac           | 1     |     11 |
| mac           | 1     |      1 |
| mac           | 1     |      8 |
| sdcard        | 1     |      0 |
| sdcard        | 1     |      9 |
| sdcard        | 1     |     11 |
| sdcard        | 1     |      1 |
| sdcard        | 1     |      8 |
| usb           | 1     |      0 |
| usb           | 1     |      8 |
| usb           | 1     |      9 |
| usb           | 1     |     20 |
| usb           | 1     |      5 |
| usb           | 1     |      7 |
| usb           | 1     |      4 |
| usb           | 1     |      1 |
| usb           | 1     |      2 |
| ethernet      | 1     |      0 |
| ethernet      | 1     |      1 |
| ethernet      | 1     |      4 |
| ethernet      | 1     |      2 |
| ethernet      | 1     |      5 |
| wifi          | 1     |      0 |
| wifi          | 1     |      5 |
| wifi          | 1     |      1 |
| wifi          | 1     |      2 |
| bluetooth     | 1     |      0 |
| bluetooth     | 1     |      1 |
| Display       | 1     |      0 |
| Display       | 1     |      8 |
| Display       | 1     |      4 |
| Display       | 1     |      7 |
| Display       | 1     |      9 |
| Display       | 1     |      3 |
| Display       | 1     |      1 |
| Display       | 1     |     13 |
| Display       | 1     |     15 |
| Display       | 1     |      5 |
| touchable     | 1     |      0 |
| touchable     | 1     |      2 |
| touchable     | 1     |      1 |
| Camera        | 1     |      0 |
| Scanner       | 1     |      0 |
| mobileApp     | 1     |      0 |
| Computer      | 1     |      0 |
| closedFrame   | 1     |      0 |
| closedFrame   | 1     |      1 |
| securityLock  | 1     |      1 |
| securityLock  | 1     |      0 |
| emergencyStop | 1     |      0 |
| emergencyStop | 1     |      1 |
| innerLight    | 1     |      0 |
| innerLight    | 1     |      1 |
+---------------+-------+--------+
86 rows in set (0,50 sec)
```

Mi objetivo ahora es conseguir esta misma tabla, pero con el campo "veces" dividido por 86. Es decir, el total de elementos que resultan de la consulta... del union!!!

inicialmente he englobado toda la consulta union en un select tal que asi:

```
select field, veces, cuenta 
from (
    ... // aqui va todo el select/union

) as T1;
```

Con esta consulta, vuelvo a tener la misma tabla anterior de resultados.Pero al intentar dividir por el total de elementos, con un

count(*):

> select field, veces / count(*), cuenta  from (
>       ... // aqui va todo el select/union
>
> ) as T1;

el resultado es:

```
+---------------------+-------+
| T1.field / count(*) | veces |
+---------------------+-------+
|                   0 | 1     |
+---------------------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,51 sec)
```

A alguien se le ocurre alguna forma de obtener el total de filas del union, y dividir un campo por ese total?

Gracias de antemano, y feliz navidad!!!

Answer (score 1):

Tu ejemplo está demasiado detallado, y eso complica un poco su seguimiento. Te pongo un ejemplo más sencillo de lo que quieres conseguir, a ver si te vale:

```
declare @tabla as table (
    veces int,
    nombre char(50)
)

insert into @tabla values (1, 'Hola')
insert into @tabla values (1, 'Hello')
insert into @tabla values (1, 'Adios')
insert into @tabla values (1, 'Bye')

select veces, cuenta, cast(veces as decimal) / cuenta as Ratio from (
    select count(*) as Cuenta from @tabla
) as t1  inner join @tabla
on 1 = 1
```

Es un ejemplo que divide la columna veces entre el total de filas. Yo lo he metido en una variable table para evitar hacer dos veces la consulta grande (una para calcular el total y otra para leer los registros individuales). Pero si quisieras hacerlo ejecutando dos veces la consulta grande sería así:

```
select field, cast(veces as decimal) / cuenta, cuenta from (
    select count(*) as cuenta from (
        -- Aquí iría la consulta grande
    ) as t
) as t1 inner join (
    -- Aquí iría la consulta grande
) as t2
on 1 = 1
```

Por otra parte, y si me permites que opine sobre lo que NO has preguntado, yo no haría la consulta inicial con tantos UNION que perjudican seriamente el rendimiento de la misma. ¿Te has planteado hacerlo simplemente con un GROUP BY y un CASE? Suele ser más interesante hacer una única consulta que tantas consultas con UNION.

Tampoco entiendo por qué usas CONCAT para poner un valor 1 en el campo "veces", si luego lo vas a usar como decimal para dividirlo. Seguramente haya un motivo, pero sería bueno que lo explicaras.

Comment: respecto a lo que NO pregunto, utilizo el union porque es la manera que he encontado de pivotar la tabla original para obtener los datos como me interesaban como columnas (puedes verlo en http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37576/mysql-pivotar-tabla-resultado-de-campos-json). Creo que probe el tema del group by pero no me resolvia lo que buscaba, pero si ves alguna forma te agradeceria que me la dijeras :) . Lo del Concat es una prueba, esta eliminado)

Comment: Respecto a la solucion, por lo que entiendo es hacer una subconsulta para obtener el total de los registros y luego utilizarla para la division. Lo he hecho asi, y resuelve el problema. Lo que pasa es que de optima no tiene nada la consulta :) La optimizacion la dejaremos para otro hilo en stackoverflow

Comment: La forma de hacerla óptima es no repetir la consulta dos veces, sino guardar el resultado en una tabla temporal y leer de ahí las dos veces que es súper rápido. Por cierto, si se te ha solucionado el problema, no olvides marcar la respuesta como válida, por favor. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar directamente la función **[`avg`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)**:

```
SELECT avg(veces) FROM(
     //Aquí tu select union
) AS media
```

Y te devolverá la media de los valores de la columna `veces`.

Comment: Te falta resolver la mitad del problema de @Angel (dividir un campo de T1 por el número de filas)

Comment: @DavidIsla Tienes razón, ya he modificado la respuesta. Muchas gracias por el aviso.

Answer (score 0):

Como resumen rapido, tengo que hacerlo todo en una consulta por decision tecnica (utilizamos un gestor que solo admite consultas, y no podemos programar nada en el). Ademas, tampoco me permite utilizar cosas como set @var=0. El problema principal es que no puedo hacer un count(*) o avg(*) debido a que no tengo para agrupar un id unico en el resultado. :(

De todas formas ya esta solucionado. No voy a fijarme en la optimización (porque esta claro que no esta optimizada). La pongo aqui por si a alguien le sirve... si estuvieramos en halloween daria muuucho miedo... ;)

```
select  field, if(cuenta>0, 100, 0) /
(select count(*) from(
  select
      concat("assembled") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.assembled')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.assembled'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("windows") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("linux") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("mac") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.osMac')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osMac'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("sdcard") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("usb") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.usb')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.usb'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("ethernet") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("wifi") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.wifi')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.wifi'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("bluetooth") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("Display") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay'),NULL))as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("touchable") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("Camera") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.integratedCamera')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedCamera'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("Scanner") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.builtinScanner')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.builtinScanner'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("mobileApp") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.mobileApp')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.mobileApp'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("Computer") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.integratedComputer')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedComputer'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("closedFrame") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.closedFrame')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.closedFrame'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("securityLock") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.securityLock')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.securityLock'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("emergencyStop") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.emergencyStop')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.emergencyStop'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  union
  select
      concat("innerLight") as field,
      count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.innerLight')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.innerLight'),NULL)) as cuenta
      from bigdata_filtered group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
  )as C1

)

 as cuenta
from (
select
    concat("assembled") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.assembled')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.assembled'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("windows") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osWindows'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("linux") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osLinux'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("mac") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.osMac')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.osMac'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("sdcard") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.sdCard'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("usb") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.usb')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.usb'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("ethernet") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.ethernet'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("wifi") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.wifi')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.wifi'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("bluetooth") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.bluetooth'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("Display") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedDisplay'),NULL))as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("touchable") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.touchableDisplay'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("Camera") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.integratedCamera')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedCamera'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("Scanner") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.builtinScanner')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.builtinScanner'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("mobileApp") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.mobileApp')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.mobileApp'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("Computer") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.integratedComputer')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.integratedComputer'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("closedFrame") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.closedFrame')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.closedFrame'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("securityLock") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.securityLock')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.securityLock'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered  group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("emergencyStop") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.emergencyStop')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.emergencyStop'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
union
select
    concat("innerLight") as field,
    count(if(json_extract(filters, '$.innerLight')= true,json_extract(filters, '$.innerLight'),NULL)) as cuenta
    from bigdata_filtered group by concat(ip, filtered_date)
) as T1
;
```