# Cláusula WHERE por columna

Tags: sql-server

Buenas necesito sacar una tabla de consultas la cual me muestre la media por horas en varias columnas pero cada columna tiene que tener una condición y deben recogerse en la misma fila por horas, he intentado lo siguiente pero me separa las horas:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(hour, Fecha) as Hora, CONVERT(INT, AVG(particulas))as PARTICULAS
from filtro1
where flag1 ='0' and fecha >= '16-03-2020 17:20:00.370' and fecha <= '17-03-2020 06:20:00.370' GROUP 
BY DATEPART(hour, Fecha)
Union 
SELECT  DATEPART(hour, Fecha) as Hora ,AVG(presion) AS PRESION
from filtro1
where flag2 ='0' and fecha >= '16-03-2020 17:20:00.370' and fecha <= '17-03-2020 06:20:00.370' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, Fecha)
ORDER BY Hora
```

Esto me arroja el siguiente resultado pero necesito dos columnas con filas relacionadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: En su día hice una pregunta para conseguir pivotar una tabla. Aunque mi BBDD era un poco rara, están hechas las dos consultas (para horizontal y para vertical) echa un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37576/mysql-pivotar-tabla-resultado-de-campos-json a ver si puede orientarte algo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está siendo que le estás diciendo que te ponga en la primera columna la hora y en la segunda columna las partículas y luego le añada a la consulta otros resultados, con la hora en la primera columna y las presión en la segunda. En ningún momento dices nada de la tercera columna.

Te propongo la solución más sencilla para cambiarlo (más sencilla en el sentido de más natural, no en el de más eficiente), hacer las consultas y luego una consulta sobre ellas.

```
SELECT q.Hora, SUM(q.PARTICULAS), SUM(q.PRESION)
FROM (
SELECT DATEPART(hour, Fecha) as Hora, CONVERT(INT, AVG(particulas)) as PARTICULAS, 0 as PRESION
FROM filtro1
WHERE flag1 ='0' AND fecha >= '16-03-2020 17:20:00.370' AND fecha <= '17-03-2020 06:20:00.370' GROUP 
BY DATEPART(hour, Fecha)
UNION
SELECT DATEPART(hour, Fecha) as Hora, 0 AS PARTICULAS, AVG(presion) AS PRESION
FROM filtro1
WHERE flag2 ='0' AND fecha >= '16-03-2020 17:20:00.370' AND fecha <= '17-03-2020 06:20:00.370' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, Fecha)
) q
GROUP BY q.Hora
ORDER BY q.Hora
```

Comment: Buenas, no consigo hacer que funcione, da errores de sintaxis. Gracias.

Comment: Editado. No puedo probarlo ahora mismo, y te estoy respondiendo a pelo, sin  hacer pruebas, pero así debería de funcionar.

Comment: funciona gracias.